# Changing the Laravel redirect location after registration not working - Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, custom-routes, laravel-5.6

I changed `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` to `protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';` in `RegisterController.php`, But it's not working. Redirection is working fine for `LoginController.php`. I changed `/home` to `/dashboard` in possible everywhere. Why after registration the redirection url not working, would someone help me please? (sorry for my bad english).

```
RegisterController.php

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried clearning your cache? There are lots of resources out there to explain how to do this for your version of laravel Also, can you post your routes file?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got the solution. Already I accepted one answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override redirectPath() in your register controller

```
protected function redirectPath()
{
  if (Auth::user()->role==0) {
    return '/dashboard';
  } else {
    return '/home';
  }
}
```

or you can redirect 'home' rout to 'dashboard'

```
Route::get('home', function(){
return redirect(url(/dashboard));
});
```